# Mysql_fetch_array() supplied argument is not a valid mysql result resource

Tags: php, mysql

Все делаю как всегда, но почему то не работает. Все время работало. С чего такая ошибка???

```
 <?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("blog");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT date FROM index", $connect);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo mysql_error();
 ?>
```

Comment: никто не поможет???

Comment: Какая-то ошибка, посмотрите ````var_dump($result)````. Проверяйте ошибку ДО парсинга результата.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибки где проверяются?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT date FROM index", $connect);
if( !$result )
{
    print "mysql_query(): ".mysql_error();
}
```

Что-то мне подсказывает, что должно быть:

```
"SELECT `date` FROM `index`"
```